# Incident, reflected, and standing waves

Tags: optics, waves

How do you show that the incident and reflected waves of an electromagnetic wave that is reflected backward off a mirror coated with a conducing material add to give a standing wave?

Comment: Can you please complete your question so that it would become visible to others?

Also, you should show the research that you've done on the topic. Simply asking questions makes no sense. You need to tell, where are you actually stuck. Welcome to SE! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standing wave is the superposition of waves of the same frequency but opposite propagation direction like the incident and reflected wave on a metal mirror.

Thus for the electric field of an electromagnetic wave propagating in positive z-direction and reflected at a mirror at $z=0$, where the field and thus the sum of amplitudes $E_i+E_r=0$ is zero, using Euler's formula you get the standing wave $$ E=E_i\exp{i(\omega t-kz)}+E_r\exp{i(\omega t+kz)}= 2iE_i\exp{(i\omega t)}\sin {(kz)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Should we posit a source or see the wave as trapped in a cavity? I don't see how a wave packet bouncing off a mirror will lead to a standing wave that is not transient.

In any case, you would decompose the wave in Fourier modes and establish the boundary conditions of the mirror and of the source/other mirror. These boundary conditions will determine the steady state of your system.

The standing waves then appear as a sum of modes of opposite wave vectors. The travelling components of the modes will cancel out, yielding the product of an oscillating phase factor and an envelope, or a standing wave.

Answer (score 1):

[image: standing wave]
<sub>(source: [ucla.edu](http://demoweb.physics.ucla.edu/sites/default/files/instructional_lab_manuals_physics_6b_experiment_2_experiment_2_files/instructionallab_manualsphysics6bexperiment_2fig_3.png))</sub>

If you show an image, similar to the one above, that illustrates the wave  reflecting from the surface at a point in the wave where it is intersecting the line of origin (this would be every half wavelength), then the reflected wavelength would be the inverse of the incoming wave of incidence, causing the two waves to appear to be a single standing wave.

However, this apparent standing wave would only occur every half wavelength and would not exhibit the properties of a legitimate standing wave, but perhaps I am not understanding the question completely...